# Push button link with blink LED

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I'm very new to HDL coding. I'm using Xilinx verilog for HDL coding.

I'm trying to implement a push btn to activate the LED blinking code below and when button is released, blinking stops. Below is the blinking LED code

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module blinkyslow(
    input CLOCK, SW,
    output LED
    );
    reg [24:0] COUNT = 25'b0000000000000000000000000;
    reg LED=1;
    always @(posedge CLOCK) begin
    COUNT <= COUNT + 1;
    LED <= (COUNT == 25'b0000000000000000000000000)?~LED:LED;
    end
endmodule
```

I'm using basys 3 board and i'm trying to link variable SW as the switch

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: What is the problem, you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps  
module blinkyslow(  
    input CLOCK, SW,reset,  
    output reg LED  
    );  
    reg [24:0] COUNT;  
    always @(posedge CLOCK) begin  
      if ( reset ==1'b1)  
        LED <= 1'b0;
        COUNT <= 0;
      else  
        begin  
    COUNT <= COUNT + 1;  
    LED <= SW & ((COUNT == 25'b0)?~LED:LED);  
        end  
      end  
endmodule
```

Since the always block is only sensitive to the rising edge of the CLOCK signal, the reset signal is a synchronous reset.

Comment: Please format your code and describe what it is doing.

Comment: this worked perfectly fine, what I do not understand is "if (reset == 1'b1) " part. I set my constraints of reset to a push button.

So what I'm guessing is since I'm not pressing on the push button therefore it is open circuit and its always returning a "1" therefore my LED doesnt light up. 

right?

Comment: it's very simple. before reseting the circuit, LED has a unknown value ( 1'bx). if you want to use this circuit, you should press "reset" button. It's supposed that the "reset" is ACTIVE_HIGH with pull down structure.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can implement it by having the counter increment only if the button is pressed.

(Strictly speaking, this is not good because if `COUNT` stays zero, `LED` will be toggled at evely clock. Toggling `LED` only if the button is pressed will solve this)

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module blinkyslow(
    input CLOCK, SW,
    output LED
    );
    reg [24:0] COUNT = 25'b0000000000000000000000000;
    reg LED=1;
    always @(posedge CLOCK) begin
        if (SW) begin
            COUNT <= COUNT + 1;
            LED <= (COUNT == 25'b0000000000000000000000000)?~LED:LED;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

(not tested, assuming `SW = 1` means the switch on the board is pressed)

Answer (score 0):

@Nicholas Chan. In your original code, you have defined the following line not in **initial** block. Hence, LED is hardwired to zero.

`reg LED=1;`

so either define a reset signal for LED and COUNT (as in earlier answer )or you can try using the following code using initial block

`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module blinkyslow(
    input CLOCK, SW,
    output LED
    );
    initial:begin
        reg [24:0] COUNT = 25'b0000000000000000000000000;
        reg LED=1;
    end
    always @(posedge CLOCK) begin
    COUNT <= COUNT + 1;
    LED <= (COUNT == 25'b0000000000000000000000000)?~LED:LED;
    end
endmodule`